# Run time analysis on a nested for loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to find the run time on each line, when the best case and worst case would occur, and the Big-O in worst and best case.

What the code i pasted does is find the the longest length of the sequence of ascending numbers in array.

For example if we had [4,5,6,9,1,2,3,4,5,6] , the longest sequence would be 6.

will the first for loop will be executed n times?

 will the second for loop be executed n times?

 will the if statement be executed n times?

 will the statement inside the if, be executed n times?

Will the best case occur when the array is in ascending order and the worst occur when the array is in descending order?

The reason I don't believe this to be true is that, when it is sorted in ascending order the second loop will be ran all the way through. When it is sorted in descending order, the second loop will always break because the and statement does not hold true.

```java
for (i = 0, length = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
  for (i1 = i2 = k = i; k < n-1 && a[k] < a[k+1]; k++, i2++);
  if (length < i2 - i1 + 1)
    length = i2 - i1 + 1;
}
return length;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the variables `i1` and `i2` are not really needed, as `i1 == i` and `i2 == k` at each iteration of the inner loop, so we can just write:

```
for (i = 0, length = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
  for (k = i; k < n-1 && a[k] < a[k+1]; k++);
  if (length < k - i + 1)
    length = k - i + 1;
}
return length;
```

The outer loop will execute n-1 times. No difference in worst/best case there.

The best case occurs when `a` is a non-increasing sequence. In that case `a[k] < a[k+1]` will never be true and thus the inner loop's condition will only be executed once. The return value will in that case be 1, and the time complexity *O(n)*.

The worst case occurs when `a` is an ever increasing sequence. In that case `a[k] < a[k+1]` will always be true, and thus the inner loop's condition will iterate *n-1 - i* times, the loop's condition once time more when `k < n-1` is false.

The `if` condition and the adjustment of `length` execute in constant time.

The nested loop's body (the `if`) executes in total as many times as one can make a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) of 2 elements (represented by `i` and `k`) from a set of *n-1* elements. The formula for that is (n-1)n/2, which is *O(n²)*.

Comment: Can you explain how you get (n-1)*n/2? I know the sum identity is (n)(n+1)/2, so are you just taking n-1 (the number of elements) and putting them in the sum identity?

Comment: Yes, it would be n(n+1)/2 if the loop condition were `< n` instead of `< n-1`.